# sigmaJS noverlap with large graph

Tags: sigma.js

I have a graph with up to 4000++ of nodes and edges and I actually want to do a free-style layout. I am using sigmaJS and tried to implement the noverlap.

Resource: https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/tree/master/plugins/sigma.layout.noverlap

I tried to set the gridSize and speed to a large number, but the rendering part is quite slow. Can I get guidance on the configuration I should set so that the rendering will be faster or what might cause the slow rendering that I should check?